# In c, when I use %s to print out the contents of a char array it prints blank, but when I loop over it and print each character it works

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, printf

Just implementing a simple sorting algorithm to sort a string. I tried printing out the buff char array with printf("%s\n") but it came out blank. The contents of the array are there, though, and I checked with printing out each character of it. What am I missing here?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: ./sortstring string");
        exit(1);
    }

    int size = 1; // 1 to account for '\0'
    for (int i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        size += 1;
    }
    char buff[size];
    strcpy(buff, argv[1]);

    char temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (tolower(buff[i]) > tolower(buff[j]))
            {
                temp = buff[i];
                buff[i] = buff[j];
                buff[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    // printf("%s\n", buff);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", buff[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Hint: what *results do you get* from the `%c` prints? in particular, do you see a zero value at the start? Where do you suppose that might have come from? (Think carefully about the meaning of the `size` variable in your program, and the bounds of the for-loop iteration.) Do you understand why that would cause a problem for printing with `%s`? (Hint: think about the comment, `// 1 to account for '\0'`. What function does that `char` with value `'\0'` serve?)

Answer (score 2):

Change `"%c"` to `"%d"` in `printf` and see the result.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", buff[i]);
    }
```

`strcpy` copies terminating null byte with the source string.
You sorted terminating null byte with other characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting function is probably sorting the null character to position 0.

Comment: I can't speak for the downvoter, but they may have felt this answer A) lacks elaboration, and B) uses "probably" where an answer should be more certain. Altogether it does feel more like a comment than answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're initializing `size` with 1. I know you did that because you need one more char to \0, but after that, either you need to loop through `size - 1` or you can decrease the value of size before your `for` loops.

Another thing you can do is: initialize `size` with 0, and use `size + 1` while creating your array.

Comment: Your answer nicely specifies multiple ways of fixing the problem, but it neither explains why OP's code is wrong, nor why your proposed solutions fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to manually count characters in "argc[1]", you could just use the "strlen" function.  So, instead of

```
int size = 1; // 1 to account for '\0'
for (int i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    size += 1;
}
```

You could use

```
int size = strlen(argv[1]);
```

Regards.

Comment: While this is a useful suggestion, it is not an answer to the question. It does not explain why `printf("%s\n", buff);` does not work, whereas printing every character individually does.

Comment: The function `strlen` will return the length of the string **not** including the terminating null character. Therefore, the code line from the question `char buff[size];` will declare an array that does not have any room for the terminating null charcter, if it is used together with your posted code. This means that the next line `strcpy(buff, argv[1]);` will write to the array out of bounds, invoking undefined behavior.